# Update: Spring Boot JMS static reply queue on IBM MQ Series

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

In my use case I need to do request-reply call to a remote system via managed queues. Using Spring Boot and IBM's MQ starter I have the problem that the application wants to create dynamic/temporary reply queues instead of using the already existing managed queue.

Configuration is set up here

```
@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class QueueConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory factory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    factory.setTransportType(CT_WMQ);                  // is 1
    factory.setHostName(queueProperties.getHost());
    factory.setPort(queueProperties.getPort());
    factory.setChannel(queueProperties.getChannel());  // combo of ${queueManager}%${channel}
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public JmsMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    JmsMessagingTemplate jmt = new JmsMessagingTemplate(connectionFactory);
    jmt.setDefaultDestinationName(queueProperties.getQueueName());
    return jmt;
  }

  @Bean
  public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.foo.model");
    return marshaller;
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageConverter messageConverter(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    MarshallingMessageConverter converter = new MarshallingMessageConverter();
    converter.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    converter.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    return converter;
  }
}
```

Usage is pretty straight forward: Take the object convert and send it. Wait for response receive
and convert it.

```
@Component
public class ExampleSenderReceiver {

  @Autowired
  private JmsMessagingTemplate jmsMessagingTemplate;

  @Override
  @SneakyThrows
  public ResponseExample sendAndReceive(RequestExample request, String correlationId) {
    MessagePostProcessor mpp = message -> {
      message = MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message)
          .setHeader(JmsHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, correlationId)
          // .setHeader(JmsHeaders.REPLY_TO, "DEV.QUEUE.3") this triggers queue creation
          .build();
      return message;
    };
    String destination = Objects.requireNonNull(jmsMessagingTemplate.getDefaultDestinationName());
    return jmsMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(destination, request, ResponseExample.class, mpp);
  }
```

I read already a lot of IBM documentation and think, I need to set the [message type](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q022870_.html) to "MQMT_REQUEST" but I do not find the right spot to do so.

## Update

Added Spring Integration as [Gary proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66871626/4657396) and added a configuration for JmsOutboundGateway

```
  @Bean
  public MessageChannel requestChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public QueueChannel responseChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel" )
  public JmsOutboundGateway jmsOutboundGateway( ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    JmsOutboundGateway gateway = new JmsOutboundGateway();
    gateway.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    gateway.setRequestDestinationName("REQUEST");
    gateway.setReplyDestinationName("RESPONSE");
    gateway.setReplyChannel(responseChannel());
    gateway.setCorrelationKey("JMSCorrelationID*");
    gateway.setIdleReplyContainerTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return gateway;
  }
```

And adapted my ExampleSenderReceiver class

```
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("requestChannel")
 private MessageChannel requestChannel;
   
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("responseChannel")
 private QueueChannel responseChannel;

 @Override
 @SneakyThrows
 public ResponseExample sendAndReceive(RequestExample request, String correlationId) {
   String xmlContent = "the marshalled request object";   

   Map<String, Object> header = new HashMap<>();
   header.put(JmsHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, correlationId);

   GenericMessage<String> message1 = new GenericMessage<>(xmlContent, header);
   requestChannel.send(message1);
   log.info("send done" );

   Message<?> receive = responseChannel.receive(1500);
   if(null != receive){
     log.info("incoming: {}", receive.toString());
   }
 }
```

The important part is *gateway.setCorrelationKey("JMSCorrelationID*");*

Without that line the correlationId was not propagated correct.

Next step is re-adding MessageConverters and make it nice again.

Thank you.

Comment: An alternative way is to use `send` on the jmsTemplate and not `sendAndReceive`. Remembering to set REPLY_TO on the outgoing message. You can then set up a regular `listener` on the reply to queue.

Comment: This was another initial idea, but then the context of the call needs to be cached and the response must be correlated manually. There is also a requirement to collect only responses which belong to a request, therefore the dynamic message selector from the gateway are perfectly suited for this use case.

Comment: Good point. I guess you would have needed to use message headers. The request adding a message header setting, the responder adding the same to the reply, and the listener using a selector on the header setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default JmsTemplate (used by the `JmsMessagingTemplate`) always uses a temporary reply queue. You can subclass it and override `doSendAndReceive(Session session, Destination destination, MessageCreator messageCreator)` to use your managed queue instead.

However, it will only work if you have one request outstanding at a time (e.g. all run on a single thread). You will also have to add code for discarding "late" arrivals by checking the correlation id.

You can use async sends instead and handle replies on a listener container and correlate the replies to the requests.

Consider using `spring-integration-jms` and its outbound gateway instead - it has much more flexibility in reply queue handling (and does all the correlation for you).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-outbound-gateway

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the queue manager.

```
ibm:
  mq:
    queueManager: QM1
    channel: chanel
    connName: localhost(1414)
    user: admin
    password: admin
```

Comment: The queue manager is part of the channel property, I wrote it in the comment behind.